# Align all panel elements left CSS and Bootstrap Twitter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Im trying to align the panel elements (name and email ) left near the image , but it doesn't works something messes up my other panel.
Here is a link in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8LPC7k1IGV)

and here is the code im using:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 style=";text-align:center;font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-weight:500;">PROFILE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:center;">TEST</h4>
                <hr>
                    <img src="administrata/.jpg" class="thumbnail" style="height:100px; ">
                    <p style="">Name Surname</p>
                    <ul><li><p>E - mail: <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">email@here.com</a></p></li></ul>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:center;">TEST</h4>
                <hr>
                    <img src="administrata/.jpg" class="thumbnail" style="height:100px; ">
                    <p style="">Name Surname</p>
                    <ul><li><p>E - mail: <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">email@here.com</a></p></li></ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tell me if u need any explanation.

EDIT:

I have tryed this code but wont help:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:center;">TEST</h4>
                <hr>
              <img src="administrata/.jpg" class="thumbnail" style="height:100px;float:left ">
                    <p style="float:left">Name Surname</p>
              <ul style="float:left"><li><p>E - mail: <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">email@here.com</a></p></li></ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You using Bootstrap Twitter so you can write them indise div(col-md-12) and inside it write 2 div(col-md-6) col-md-6 or any size you want.

```
<hr>
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6"><img src="administrata/.jpg" class="thumbnail" style="height:100px;   "></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <p style="">Name Surname</p>
                <ul><li><p>E - mail: <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">email@here.com</a></p></li></ul>            </div>
              </div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media object of Bootstrap

```
<div class="media">
   <a class="pull-left" href="#">
   <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Then it like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:center;">TEST</h4>
                <hr>
                    <div class="media">
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img src="administrata/.jpg" class="thumbnail" style="height:100px; ">
                      </a>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Name Surname</h4>
                        <ul><li><p>E - mail: <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">email@here.com</a></p></li></ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:center;">TEST</h4>
                <hr>
                    <div class="media">
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img src="administrata/.jpg" class="thumbnail" style="height:100px; ">
                      </a>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Name Surname</h4>
                        <ul><li><p>E - mail: <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">email@here.com</a></p></li></ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
```